# Getting parameters from ExecutionContext

Tags: java, parameters, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job that is executed with web parameters like this:

```
https://localhost:8443/batch/async/orz003A?id=123&name=test
```

I've added these parameters, `id` and `test` to my `ExecutionContext`

I'm having trouble accessing them in my Setup Tasklet, seen below.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.yrc.mcc.app.online.NTfp211;
import com.yrc.mcc.core.batch.tasklet.AbstractSetupTasklet;


@Component
public class Tfp211SetupTasklet extends AbstractSetupTasklet {

    final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tfp211SetupTasklet.class);

    String gapId;

    @Override
    protected RepeatStatus performTask(ExecutionContext ec) {

        //TODO create the map, check the params for the needed params
        // throw an error if the param doesn't exist, because the param
        // is necessary to run the job. If the param does exist, set the specific param

        if (ec.isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.info("this shit is empty");
        }
        //setg on GAPID
        gapId = ec.toString();
        ec.get(BATCH_PROGRAM_PARAMS);
        LOGGER.info(gapId);

        ec.put(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_PROGRAM_NAME, NTfp211.class.getSimpleName());
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

edit:

Here is a piece from my AbstractSetupTaskler

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        if (!ec.containsKey(BATCH_PROGRAM_PARAMS)) {
            ec.put(BATCH_PROGRAM_PARAMS, params);
        }
```

within each job's SetupTasklet I want to specify the parameters needed for that job

edit: I have this tasklet that I believe launches my jobs

```
@Component
public class CallM204ProgramTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CallM204ProgramTasklet.class);

    @Autowired
    private CommonConfig commonConfig;

    @Autowired
    private ProgramFactory programFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MidusService midusService;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        ExecutionContext ec = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
        JobParameters jobParameters = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobParameters();
        jobParameters.getParameters();
        String progName = ec.getString(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_PROGRAM_NAME);
        Random randomSession = new Random();
        String sessionId = "000000" + randomSession.nextInt(1000000);
        sessionId = sessionId.substring(sessionId.length() - 6);
        SessionData sessionData = new SessionDataImpl("Batch_" + sessionId, commonConfig);
        IOHarness io = new BatchIOHarnessImpl(midusService, commonConfig.getMidus().getSendToMidus());
        sessionData.setIOHarness(io);
        sessionData.setUserId("mccBatch");
        Program program = programFactory.createProgram(progName, sessionData);
        String progResult = null;
        // Create necessary globals for flat file handling.
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, MccFtpFile> files = (Map<String, MccFtpFile>) ec.get(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_FTP_FILES);
        if (files != null) {
            for (MccFtpFile mccFtpFile : files.values()) {
                program.setg(mccFtpFile.getGlobalName(), mccFtpFile.getLocalFile());
            }
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> params = (Map<String, String>) ec.get(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_PROGRAM_PARAMS);
        //put params into globals
        if (params != null) {
            params.forEach((k, v) -> program.setg(k, v));
        }
        try {
            program.processUnthreaded(sessionData);
            progResult = io.close(sessionData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            progResult = "Error running renovated program " + progName + ": " + e.getMessage();
            LOGGER.error(progResult, e);
            chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(ExitStatus.FAILED);
        } finally {
            String currResult = ec.getString(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_PROGRAM_RESULT).trim();
            // Put the program result into the execution context.
            ec.putString(AbstractSetupTasklet.BATCH_PROGRAM_RESULT, currResult + "\r" + progResult);
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Comment: the code with `performTask()` is just mainly for testing purposes and can be ignored. Demonstrating some things I've done to try and access the parameters set on the `ExecutionContext`

Comment: How are you launching the job? Is `id` and `name` passed to your job as parameters? Looks like you are expecting those parameters to be in the execution context but those will not be added to the execution context unless you did it in `AbstractSetupTasklet`.

Comment: I'm launching the job with a `@RequestMapping`, I use `@RequestParam` and provide the params on the url I listed in my first post. I'll edit my post with some more code

Comment: Your edit is still not enough to pinpoint your issue. But I understand your problem. See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a job launcher and pass the parameters as described in the docs here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer.

After that, you can get access to job parameters in your tasklet from the chunk context. For example:

```
class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobParameters();
        // get id and name from jobParameters
        // use id and name to do the required work
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have something really similar, I can post in another edit

Comment: I cancelled the edit for now, I'll look at your link and see where it takes me. I'll edit my original post if I find something relevant

Comment: to get the jobParameters, would I do something like `jobParameters.getParameters();` ?

Comment: From the `JobParameters` instance, you call one of the `getXXX` methods to get a particular parameter. For example: `String nameParameter = jobParameters.getString("name");`

Comment: My tasklet extends only AbstractSetupTasklet. My 'performTask' function only takes in execution context as a param. Should I modify it to take in chunkcontext as well to access the parameters?

Comment: yes, you would need the chunk context to get access to job parameters as shown in the snippet.

Comment: Thank you. I'll modify my function and see where it takes me

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to obtain the parameters via chunkContext and then add them to execution context for my job based on your advice. I appreciate it.

Comment: Within the tasklet I want to fail the step if the job parameters aren't present. Is there any way to fail out within a tasklet?

Comment: Yes, just throw an exception.